How to implement one-way data transfer at specific intervals using SSE or WebSockets?
I'm working on a web application where I need to send data from the server to the client at specific times rather than continuously. I want to achieve this using either Server-Sent Events (SSE) or WebSockets.
Requirements:
One-way communication: Data only flows from the server to the client.
Timing control: Data should be sent only at predefined intervals or specific triggers, not continuously.
Questions:
Can I use SSE for this purpose, and if so, how would I structure the server to send messages only at specified times?
Would using WebSockets be a better approach for sending timed messages? If yes, how would that be implemented?
Are there alternative methods (like HTTP polling or long polling) that could suit my needs better?
I initially tried using Server-Sent Events (SSE), but I found that it sends data continuously, which isn't what I need.

Do the clients know the "specific times" when the new data should be sent? If so you might not have any reason to use SSE over something less (server-side) resource-intensive like AJAX polling from the clients.

The clients don’t know the specific times when the new data will be sent; it’s entirely determined by the server.
